# Mint 17 (Cinnamon): CTRL+Shift+U not letting me enter unicode symbols

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, unicode

I realize there's probably a simple answer to this question. I come from Ubuntu (Unity) and am used to type unicode symbols with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, followed by the symbol's code and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This doesn't seem to work in Mint 17 (Cinnamon). I googled around and didn't find an answer to this.

How do you enter unicode symbols?

Comment: In what program? It seems to work on my Debian Edition when typing in the `terminator` terminal. Thanks, by the way, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: What fonts are you using, do the have the unicode range that you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

The following steps fixed it for me:

1. Navigate into your System Settings → Languages → Input Methods.
2. If "IBus" is not available in the "Input Method" drop-down menu, click the "Add Support for IBus" button. Else, continue to step 3.
3. Select "IBus" from the "Input Method" dropdown Menu.
4. Restart your Machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling unicode

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unicode
```

Just done this myself and restarted, all fixed.

If applicable [sounds from question like it may well be], it's potentially to do with the way you go about 16 to 17 upgrade (OS wipe and reinstall vs. via less thorough apt-get).

I have a feeling this was the source of my problem - though I also installed the 'ancient' font to enable emojis on command line and read on the web that there have been bugs associated with this + that font.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Cinnamon on Linux Mint 17.1. In my Gnome Terminal this works <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>. (<kbd>Enter</kbd> works as well) to get the Registered symbol ® ( <- and firefox works as well), for which the [unicode hex value is AE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ae/index.htm).

I don't recall ever enabling this, so it looks like there is something missing on your setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I wonder what's happening.

Comment: @sergio That is difficult to diagnose, but I thought you wanted at least to know that it could work on Mint 17 (Cinnamon). If you move your account from Unity to Cinnamon, I would temporarily create a new user logout of Cinnamon, login as the new user and try again. To make sure it is your system and not some transferred config setting

Comment: I used a separate partition for Mint so I don't think it would be that. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Sergio Not sure if it is of any help, but I am using the US English layout with euro on 5

Comment: And of course check that Ctrl+Shift is not taken by something else.

Comment: *"Ctrl+Shift is not taken by something else"*. Yes, it can be used for national keyboard layout. For example, for switching Russian/English.

Comment: *"In my Gnome Terminal this works Ctrl+Shift+U then A+E+Space"*. **Anthon**, what do you mean? :-) We must to press SIX buttons at the same time? It looks like lesson of piano play... or guitar. Would you like to explain, what exactly user must press and release to type the Registered symbol, if you please. And about THE MAIN. Ctrl+Shift+U works in **Linux Mint 17 Qiana KDE**... in Firefox. But it does not works in terminal. I tried it in Konsole and Yakuake. May be I made something wrong in terminal.

Comment: @Nikolja If you press something at the same time there is a `+` between the keys that are marked up with `<kbd></kbd>`, that is the convention on this site And consequently if there is no `+`, you type them in sequence. Why do you have to shout about **the main**? The main what? For me it works in the gnome terminal, firefox, nemo, chrome, essentially everything except for emacs that uses Ctrl+Shift+U for something itself. I don't use konsole, yakuake, don't have them installed.

Comment: About "main". Topic-starter Sergio wrote: *"This doesn't seem to work in Mint 17"*. So I tried to answer something to **main** question of this topic. To Sergio.

Comment: Thank you, Anthon, I understand about "+". I cannot understand about A+E+Space.

Comment: There is no + between A and E, they are separately typed characters. It is just convention. http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3557/33055

Comment: :-) I repeat, I know very well, what "plus" means here. Thank you.

Comment: And still you write: "I cannot understand about A+E+Space", sorry I cannot follow you cannot understand. You just have to do it to get the result.

Comment: Yes, I understand **now**, how it works. Excuse me for misunderstanding. I asked about **for what exactly** A+E+Space combination. Now I understand, this IS code for **the Registered symbol**. I thought this is another code for enter **any** Unicode symbol. I am afraid, I was inattentive when read your answer for Sergio, sorry.

Comment: @Nikolja no problem I misread your specific problem as well. I updated the answer to make the reference to unicode value in hex for the ® symbol more specific.

Comment: Anthon wrote: *"I don't use konsole, yakuake, don't have them installed."*. Yes, of course, because you use Cinnamon. Konsole is standard program for **KDE** terminal. Yakuake is additional program for KDE too. I use **Linux Mint KDE**.

Comment: This is not a problem with Mint 17, I'm experiencing the same and thought it was this, but confirmed with Ubuntu 14 -based distro users and one Mint 17 user that it works, with `xim` being `$GTK_IM_MODULE`

Answer (score 0):

Mint 20.3 has an awesome Character Map application. It's not the command line, but for this purpose it rocks.