# How Can I Disable the Global Shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + U in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, input-method

Backstory: some Linux distributions setup a keyboard shortcut to let you enter Unicode characters, and they use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `U` as that shortcut.  As a programmer, I want to instead use that shortcut in my code editor, so I'd like to disable the system one ... but I can't seem to figure out what program is responsible for it.

Everything I've found (eg. in this question about *re-enabling* that shortcut: [How to re-enable the Ctrl+Shift+U shortcut in Cinnamon Mint 17.3?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258668/how-to-re-enable-the-ctrlshiftu-shortcut-in-cinnamon-mint-17-3)) suggests that it's dependent on my IME (input method editor).  But when I went to "Input Method" (in the system menu), it said I didn't have an IME selected.

I then tried switching to the Fcitx IME (since I *would* like to be able to type Japanese characters), but that didn't help. Also, I went through all of the Fcitx configuration, and couldn't find any mention of a `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `U` shortcut in it.

My question is: how can I disable this global `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `U` shortcut?  Preferably with the Fcitx IME, but if I have to disable it I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution which works:

https://superuser.com/a/1334194

Run whichever editor you have via:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim youreditor
```

Comment: That's great ... on a per-app basis.  Is there truly no way to disable it globally though?

Comment: You can place it in e.g. `/etc/environment` if you're brave enough. Or add it via `/etc/profile.d/no-xim.sh` - the choice is yours.

Answer (score 15):

Change the keyboard shortcut in the IBus Preferences.

From terminal run `ibus-setup` to load following configuration window and remove the crtl+shift+u keyboard shortcuts entry.

[image]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug listed here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1885914

The solution that I found is to remove the ibus package:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ibus
$ sudo apt-get purge ibus
```

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan and reinstall ibus:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus
```

Go to language suport and set the iBus method, for user and root

In the terminal for user and root:

```
ibus-setup
```

and change the shortcuts in the emoji tab

In the terminal for user and root:

```
im-config
```

and set ibus

For user in the terminal:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Include the following lines at the end:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Comment: ibus-setup worked for me. Just go to "Emoji" tab and remove unicode point shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with using `dconf-editor` just go to `/desktop/ibus/panel/emoji` find `unicode-hotkey`, change the default value to nothing and save changes. You don't have to logout-login.

Answer (score 2):

`gsettings` method (same results as changing Unicode code point in IBus Preferences)

To unset shortcut:

```bash
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey "[]"
```

To restore shortcut:

```bash
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey "['<Control><Shift>u']"
```